# How do I make sure WPF sub-menuitems don't go out of my main window in restore mode?

Tags: wpf, xaml

How do I make sure my sub menu-items stay within the main window like below in restore mode?

[image]

Here is a small portion of my code

```
<Window x:Name="Main Window" x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Icon="Notepad.ico"
        Title="Home" Height="350" Width="860.142">
    <Grid>
        <Menu x:Name="menu" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="22" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="852" Background="#FFA9D1F4">
            <MenuItem Header="_File">
                <MenuItem Header="New" Command="New"/>
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Another app.

[image]

Note: it may run fine on some computers as pointed out by @G K.

Comment: Restore mode?  I've done quite a bit of WPF, and I've never heard of that before.

Comment: I have created a new WPF window and added a menu with sub-menus. On restore or maximized size, it always displays inside the main-window itself.

Would you able to post your xaml to see what else might get impact.

Comment: @GK . it is added.

Comment: @SunMan I have tried with your code, but I can't see it going out of the window in either of the modes.

Comment: @GK interesting! then I am facing this issue only on my laptop. I tested on another computer and get the same result. This guy also said something similar but I couldn't follow the resolution. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9a8fbaa2-ff5b-49ca-9896-57713ffc7716/how-to-change-submenu-orientation?forum=wpf

Comment: Can you upload your file to this share or test mine? https://1drv.ms/f/s!AtGs0pMyD6owgyLZkCA8x7rna6jS

Comment: I ran your exe, still works fine. I think this is something else issue. Even my code does not works in your laptop. Uploaded, check it (https://1drv.ms/u/s!AtGs0pMyD6owgyRHcI3fyvCg9QRk)

Comment: you are right. I face the same issue with your app as well.